# Django function include multiple functions with return

Tags: django, function, view, insert

I just want to know what is the best practice to do multiple insert into different models

lets say that I'm collecting a customer data including

- personal information
- address information
- payment information

I collect all these info from one form one view and I want to do multiple inserts into multiple models (CustomerInfo,CustomerAddress,CustomerPayment) as below

```
def insertNewCustomer():

InsertPersonalInfo()
InsertAddressInfo()
InsertPaymentInfo()

return render()



def InsertPersonalInfo(request):
     if request.moethod == 'POST'
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return ???
     
def InsertAddressInfo(request):
         if request.moethod == 'POST'
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return ???
def InsertPaymentInfo(request):
     if request.moethod == 'POST'
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return ???
```

the problem is what should I return after I do the insert process in the first function which is
InsertPersonalInfo() to go back again to insertNewCustomer and continue from the next function which is InsertAddressInfo

I hope my question is clear :D what should I return from the nested function to return to the main function and continue from where it been called.

Answer (score 0):

> which is InsertPersonalInfo() to go back again to insertNewCustomer

You can take a look at [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect). An example of the use from the official docs will be:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

This function is very useful as you can not only redirect but also pass in extra parameters.